# Django Compressor not working in production

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

I want to use django_compressor but it's not working in my production environment.

In development (`DEBUG=True`), it's working and created `.sass-cache` & `CACHE` folders.

My `settings.py` is

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'compressor',
    'myapp',
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'com.app.static')↲
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

scss file put template directory on app.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load compress %}
<html>
<head>
    {% compress css %}
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/scss' href="{% static 'top/css/top.scss' %}" charset='utf-8'>
    {% endcompress %}
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this to `settings.py`

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
```

and compress

```
python manage.py compress
```

Comment: How do you do it without offline compression? doesn't work for me with COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True and  COMPRESS_ENABLED = True .. I have to run offline compression looks like.  I had to add COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT for properly running with dynamic context.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the documentation reveals the answer:
http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/

django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED should be set to True otherwise its opposite to DEBUG

**UPDATE**

Sorry that's embarrassing, I totally missed the: **COMPRESS_ENABLED = True** on your settings.

Comment: I tried this. "COMPRESS_ENABLED= not DEBUG". still not working.

Comment: One thing you can check is the collectstatic logs to see if the compression actually happened

Comment: I tried.
python manage.py collectstatic.
and, 
1 static files copied to '/opt/webapps/src/com.app.static'. But I don't know whether compressed.

Comment: copied file is not compressed.just css file.

Comment: hi, I tried "python manage.py compress".
After, that working! thank you.